# C# get original resource text for control

Tags: c#, winforms

If I change the text of a button (say, "Next" to "Finish"), is there a way of finding the original text so I can put it back, by referring to the resources (i.e. retrieve the word "Next" from the resources)?

Obviously I could store the original before changing it, but I am curious as to whether there is a more elegant way of referring to it (e.g. in the same way you refer to a resourced string: `global::MyProject.Properties.Resources.LeString`).

Answer (score 1):

1 You can try with this code based on `RessourceManager` class

```
var resman = new ResourceManager("StringResources.Strings", yourAssembly);
btnButton.Text = resman.GetString("ButtonName");
```

Link : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.resources.resourcemanager%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

2 You can also use `ResourceUtility.getString(..)`

Link :  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee435924.aspx

Comment: Hi I've tried this and I can't make it work. I thought it was to start with but actually it's not! ... am I supposed to put something else instead of `"StringResources.Strings"`? I'm also using `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()` for the assembly - is that right?

Answer (score 0):

This is based on @Aghilas' answer, based on a bit of trial-and-error to get the correct string as the first argument. Hope this'll help the next bod in search of the same question (answer?) :-) ...

```
ResourceManager rm = new ResourceManager("<myProject>.Properties.Resources", Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
myControl.Text = rm.GetString("<myControlName>");
```